# Extracting string with set no. of hyphen

Tags: python, regex

If I have an example string as follows:

```
LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-COMPANY_ORG_CHART-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-END
```

I want to extract only the first n no. of steps where n is defined by the no. of hyphens in between.

```
So if n=5,
```

I want only the first 5 steps.

Output:

```
LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING
```

I tried this:

```
s1=re.search(r'([A-za-z_].*-{0,5}[A-za-z_].*?)',s)
print(s1.group())
```

But it is giving whole string as output.

```
LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-COMPANY_ORG_CHART-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-END
In [ ]:
```

Comment: For `n=5` you can use: `r'[^-]*(?:-[^-]*){4}'`

Answer (score 6):

If this is the actual format, then regex may be overkill for the sample provided. One other option is just using string methods and indexing:

```
x='LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-COMPANY_ORG_CHART-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-END'

print('-'.join(x.split('-')[:5]))

'LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING-LEARNING'
```

Comment: This is great. Didn't realize it. If these strings are part of a pandas column any idea how to apply this? I can use map but I don't want to use map and write a function.

Comment: or does this work: 

df_column=map(lambda x : '-'.join(x.str.split('-')), df["path"]) . Is this fast enough?

Comment: You can use `apply` and `lambda`, `df['a']=df['a'].apply(lambda x: '-'.join(x.split('-')[:5]))`

Comment: Yup. I just used that. Apply is better.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
s1 = re.search(r'^([A-za-z_]+-){0,4}[A-za-z_]+',s)
print(s1)
```

(this example is for n=5)